# What is the period of validity for a Power of Attorney letter for a child travelling with a parent?

Tags: air-travel, legal, india, international-travel, children

What is usually the period of validity of Power of Attorney letter for a child travelling with one parent? Or it may be called Child Travel Consent letter.

I need to make such a letter to go from India to Dubai.

Comment: @KateGregory I'd suggest putting that as an answer.  Any letter NOT containing such a period could be subject to question / scrutiny, so it'd be a valuable answer.

Answer (score 5):

I have never seen a letter for those two countries, only for Canada-USA and Canada-Europe. With that in mind, in my experience the letter itself contains the period. For example

> I consent to X accompanying Y for the period A to B visiting C and D.

Using just a single date as the start of your consent leaves things open to interpretation. I would not risk it or presume to know how officials would interpret a letter that did not include an explicit period of validity.