# Can just guardians come with a 16y/o for US passport renewal?

Tags: usa, passports, minors

travel.state.gov states that only one parent needs to be present for the renewal for parental awareness, but when I visited another post office that handles passport renewals, they stated that a guardian can come with the minor with legal and proper guardianship papers.

So can just the legal guardians come with a 16y/o for a expedited US passport renewal?

Comment: https://travel.state.gov/content/passports/en/passports/16-and-17.html

Comment: Related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/24369/do-both-parents-need-to-apply-for-a-us-passport-for-minors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the rules regarding US passport issuance allow legal guardians to act in place of parents where necessary. This makes sense, as legal guardians, with the proper paperwork, are generally entitled to act as parents, and a regulation that prohibited guardians from doing so for passports would be impractical.

[22 CFR 51.28](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/22/51.28) gives the actual legal rules for passports for minors. The phrase "or legal guardian" is used throughout. (b)(2), which talks about passports for 16 and 17 year olds, says "The passport authorizing officer may at any time require a minor 16 years of age and above to submit the notarized consent of a parent, a legal guardian, or a person in loco parentis to the issuance of the passport." It seems that the consent of a legal guardian can substitute for that of a parent in this case.